# Which point on the sphere S:$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ is farthest from the Point P $(2,1,3)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

I have tried to use Lagrange Mulitplier here to maximize $$F:(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-3)^2$$ subject to the constraint of S, i.e $$\nabla{F}=\lambda.\nabla{S}$$and got $\lambda=1\pm\sqrt{14}$, which in turn gives values for $(x,y,z)$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}(\pm2,\pm1,\pm3)$. I dont know how to narrow down my choice to find my point. Kindly help.

Comment: Intuitively, if we draw the line through $(2,3,1)$ and the center of our sphere $(0,0,0)$, we get two points of intersection, one of which is the point on the sphere closest to $(2,3,1)$ and the other one the farthest away, wouldn't you agree? (If this is hard to see, sketch a similar situation in two dimensions). It's actually really easy to compute this second point of intersection, and then all you need to do is *prove* that this is indeed the desired point by playing around with some inequalities.

Comment: From the work you have already done, remember you are trying to *maximize* the function. When you find multiple points in an optimization problem, what do you do with the points to figure out which ones are the absolute maxes or mins?

Comment: There are just two points. Compute the two distances. (Though by simple reasoning the correct sign is obvious.)

Comment: First question - are you required to use Lagrange Multiplier method or is it something you chose to use?

Comment: The notation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}(\pm2,\pm1,\pm3)$ is not a good one, since it suggests that there are eight solutions. It would have been better to have written $\pm\frac1{\sqrt{14}}(2,1,3)$.

Comment: @Mastrem Ohkk. I think I can use your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @NinadMunshi Second derivative is what comes to my mind

Comment: @MathLover Its just the first thing that striked me. Question didnt specify

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But there are eight octants right?  and each point will satisfy the sphere equation..https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Octant_numbers.svg

Comment: Yes, there are eight octants. That doesn't change the fact that, in this case, the equations that you get when you apply the method of Lagrange multipliers only have the two solutions that I have mentioned.

Comment: @санкетмхаске In that case, I would suggest you think through that the point that would be the farthest from the given point $P (2, 1, 3)$ is on the line going through $P$ and the center of the sphere $(0, 0, 0)$. The direction vector is $(0 - 2, 0 - 1, 0 - 3) = (-2, -1, -3)$ and as the radius of the sphere is $1$, the point that you are interested in is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}}(-2, -1, -3)$.

Comment: @MathLover Oh Yeas. Using Direction ratio of line its straight forward. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome!